# Intellij IDEA Java project and JNI

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

Is it possible for the pure Java project, created at Intellij IDEA, to use .so files (like Android project does)?

Surfing over internet I can not find any information about it. Sounds very strange.

UPDATE:

What I have in Android is a simple script:

```
def ndkBuild;
def ndkBuildingDir = mainSrcDir;
def hasNdk = false;
if (System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME != null) {
    hasNdk = true;
    ndkBuild = new File(System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME, ndkBuildFilename())
}

commandLine ndkBuild, "--directory", ndkBuildingDir, "APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=${ndkBuildingDir}/native/Android.mk", "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=${ndkBuildingDir}/native/Application.mk"
```

And I can not found any documentation of doing such things at Java project.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

However it will stop being a pure Java project and will introduce a dependency on a system the native binary is compiled on/written for.

To do this, write JNi code, like you would do on android (as you seem to be familiar with that), compile into a dynamic library with certain compiler flags and then use `System.loadLibrary("foo");` in your Java code, just like you would on an android project.

There's really a lot more to this though, and there's quite a few [tutorials](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) online that describe how to do this. I would suggest to try to solve the problem in Java before opting for JNI though as there's a lot of places to stumble and cause serious bugs in JNI.

I've never written any JNI code in IDEA though, I'm sure it's possible but it's not really a C or C++ IDE, so you might want to use something else for that part.

Comment: What I have now is a Gradle script to use Android NDK to build .co files:
def ndkBuild = new File(System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME, ndkBuildFilename())
    commandLine ndkBuild, "--directory", ndkBuildingDir, "APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=${ndkBuildingDir}/native/Android.mk", "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=${ndkBuildingDir}/native/Application.mk"
What I can't find is a documentation of how to use such things at pure Java project.